# Replacing blank values (white space) with NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find all values in a Pandas dataframe that contain whitespace (any arbitrary amount) and replace those values with NaNs.

Any ideas how this can be improved?

Basically I want to turn this:

```
                   A    B    C
2000-01-01 -0.532681  foo    0
2000-01-02  1.490752  bar    1
2000-01-03 -1.387326  foo    2
2000-01-04  0.814772  baz     
2000-01-05 -0.222552         4
2000-01-06 -1.176781  qux
```

Into this:

```
                   A     B     C
2000-01-01 -0.532681   foo     0
2000-01-02  1.490752   bar     1
2000-01-03 -1.387326   foo     2
2000-01-04  0.814772   baz   NaN
2000-01-05 -0.222552   NaN     4
2000-01-06 -1.176781   qux   NaN
```

I've managed to do it with the code below, but man is it ugly. It's not Pythonic and I'm sure it's not the most efficient use of pandas either. I loop through each column and do boolean replacement against a column mask generated by applying a function that does a regex search of each value, matching on whitespace.

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i][df[i].apply(lambda i: True if re.search('^\s*$', str(i)) else False)]=None
```

It could be optimized a bit by only iterating through fields that could contain empty strings:

```
if df[i].dtype == np.dtype('object')
```

But that's not much of an improvement

And finally, this code sets the target strings to None, which works with Pandas' functions like `fillna()`, but it would be nice for completeness if I could actually insert a `NaN` directly instead of `None`.

Comment: What you really want is to be able to use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#missing-data-replace) with a regex... (perhaps this should be requested as a feature).

Comment: I made a github issue for this feature: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2285 . Would be grateful for PRs! :)

Comment: For those that want to turn exactly a single blank character to missing, see [this simple solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105408/3707607)

Answer (score 344, accepted):

I think `df.replace()` does the job, since [pandas 0.13](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [-0.532681, 'foo', 0],
    [1.490752, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.387326, 'foo', 2],
    [0.814772, 'baz', ' '],     
    [-0.222552, '   ', 4],
    [-1.176781,  'qux', '  '],         
], columns='A B C'.split(), index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-01-06'))

# replace field that's entirely space (or empty) with NaN
print(df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True))
```

Produces:

```
                   A    B   C
2000-01-01 -0.532681  foo   0
2000-01-02  1.490752  bar   1
2000-01-03 -1.387326  foo   2
2000-01-04  0.814772  baz NaN
2000-01-05 -0.222552  NaN   4
2000-01-06 -1.176781  qux NaN
```

---

As [Temak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351629/temak) pointed it out, use `df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)` in case your valid data contains white spaces.

Comment: cannot understand why `pd.Series(["1", "#", "9", " .", None]).replace(regex=r"( +\.)|#").values` gives `['1', '#', '9', ' .', ' .']`

Comment: regex is a boolean flag.  Maybe you mean `pd.Series(["1", "#", "9", " .", None]).replace(r"( +\.)|#", "X", regex=True).values` which gives `['1', 'X', '9', 'X', None]`

Comment: 2 years on, I've changed the accepted answer to this, now that pandas supports it. Thanks!

Comment: @patricksurry regex may be string: `frame.replace(regex=r"( +\.)|#", value=pd.np.NaN, inplace=True)`

Comment: @winand wow, never spotted that.  It's unclear from docs how `value=None` (or omitted) should behave but seems like `s.replace(regex=r"( +\.)|#").values` should be equal to `s.replace(r"( +\.)|#", regex=True)`.  Maybe file a bug https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues ?

Comment: **NOTE**: if you don't want an element containing space in the middle to be replaced with NaN use `df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: I tried to use this, but found out that r'^\s*$' should be the expression to use. 
without ^ and $ it will match any string with two consecutive blanks.
Also changed + to * to include the empty string "" in the list of things to convert to NaN

Comment: I am trying your solution in my code, but it has no effect. I am trying "energy["Energy Supply"].replace(to_replace = "...", value = np.NaN)". Wanting to change the string "..." to NaN values, but it does nothing and returns the same dataframe.

Comment: @Archan Joshi, I realize this is a year ago, but you're not using inplace, which isn't reassigning it.

Comment: @ChrisClark: it's useful to note it was [pandas version 0.13 which allowed regex in `df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace). For all us looking at this years later, wondering "why are the old answers so weird?"

Answer (score 121):

If you want to replace an empty string and records with only spaces, the **correct answer is**!:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

The accepted answer

```
df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Does not replace an empty string!, you can try yourself with the given example slightly updated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [-0.532681, 'foo', 0],
    [1.490752, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.387326, 'fo o', 2],
    [0.814772, 'baz', ' '],     
    [-0.222552, '   ', 4],
    [-1.176781,  'qux', ''],         
], columns='A B C'.split(), index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-01-06'))
```

Note, also that 'fo o' is not replaced with Nan, though it contains a space.
Further note, that a simple:

```
df.replace(r'', np.NaN)
```

Does not work either - try it out.

Answer (score 42):

I did this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

or

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x).replace('', np.nan)
```

You can strip all str, then replace empty str with `np.nan`.

Comment: lambda x: x.str.strip() should be lambda x: x.strip()?
minor suggestion: add .astype(str) in front, this solves other data issues for me. This works for me: df=df.apply['column'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.strip()).replace('', np.nan)

Comment: The second line of code handles both int/float and string type columns. Nice. Tks!

Answer (score 40):

How about:

```
d = d.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and x.isspace() else x)
```

The `applymap` function applies a function to every cell of the dataframe.

Comment: What a nice improvement! I should have thought of this in retrospect, but got hung up on doing boolean replacements for some reason. One question - is there an advantage to doing the basestring check vs. just str(x).isspace()?

Comment: @ChrisClark: Either one is fine, although I would guess that the `isinstance` will be a bit faster.

Comment: The reference to "basestring" in the code above will not work in Python 3.... in that case, try using "str" instead.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't replace empty strings `''`. To consider also empty strings, use: `d = d.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and (not x or x.isspace()) else x)`

Comment: In Python 3.x, the correct equivalent for `isinstance(x, basestring)` is `isinstance(x, str)`

Answer (score 16):

If you are exporting the data from the CSV file it can be as simple as this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_csv, na_values=' ')
```

This will create the data frame as well as replace blank values as Na

Comment: Another option..using `skipinitialspace=True` also removes any whitespace after the delimiter which would cause any length of white space, empty strings to be read as `nan`. However if you want to retain the initial spaces for what ever reason then this option is not a good choice.

Answer (score 8):

**Simplest of all solutions:**

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

For a very fast and simple solution where you check equality against a single value, you can use the `mask` method.

```
df.mask(df == ' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print(df.isnull().sum()) # check numbers of null value in each column

modifiedDf=df.fillna("NaN") # Replace empty/null values with "NaN"

# modifiedDf = fd.dropna() # Remove rows with empty values

print(modifiedDf.isnull().sum()) # check numbers of null value in each column
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.
When I import my csv file I added na_values = ' '. Spaces are not included in the default NaN values.

```
df= pd.read_csv(filepath,na_values = ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

These are all close to the right answer, but I wouldn't say any solve the problem while remaining most readable to others reading your code. I'd say that answer is a combination of [BrenBarn's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445630/10583199) and tuomasttik's comment below that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445630/10583199). BrenBarn's answer utilizes `isspace` builtin, but does not support removing empty strings, as OP requested, and  I would tend to attribute that as the standard use case of replacing strings with null.

I rewrote it with `.apply`, so you can call it on a `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame`.

---

***Python 3:***

*To replace empty strings or strings of entirely spaces:*

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) and (x.isspace() or not x) else x)
```

*To replace strings of entirely spaces:*

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) and x.isspace() else x)
```

---

To use this in Python 2, you'll need to replace `str` with `basestring`.

***Python 2:***

*To replace empty strings or strings of entirely spaces:*

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and (x.isspace() or not x) else x)
```

*To replace strings of entirely spaces:*

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, basestring) and x.isspace() else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but what does seem to work is saving to XLSX and then importing it back. The other solutions on this page did not work for me, unsure why.

```
data.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
data = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
df.loc[df.Variable == '', 'Variable'] = 'Value'
```

or

```
df.loc[df.Variable1 == '', 'Variable2'] = 'Value'
```

Comment: is Variable a column name? and also when quoted as a string? this seems succinct but the example is too terse to follow.

Answer (score -3):

you can also use a filter to do it.

```
df = PD.DataFrame([
    [-0.532681, 'foo', 0],
    [1.490752, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.387326, 'foo', 2],
    [0.814772, 'baz', ' '],     
    [-0.222552, '   ', 4],
    [-1.176781,  'qux', '  '])
    df[df=='']='nan'
    df=df.astype(float)
```

Comment: Every line of this code (not including data) is faulty.