# Replace WhiteSpace with a 0 in Pandas (Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas

simple question here -- how do I replace all of the whitespaces in a column with a zero?

For example:

```
  Name       Age
  John       12
  Mary 
  Tim        15
```

into

```
  Name       Age
  John       12
  Mary       0
  Tim        15
```

I've been trying using something like this but I am unsure how Pandas actually reads whitespace:

```
 merged['Age'].replace(" ", 0).bfill()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built in method [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) and set param `convert_numeric=True`:

```
In [12]:
# convert objects will handle multiple whitespace, this will convert them to NaN
# we then call fillna to convert those to 0
df.Age = df[['Age']].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).fillna(0)
df
Out[12]:
   Name  Age
0  John   12
1  Mary    0
2   Tim   15
```

Comment: This is a little bit out of the scope of the OP's request, since it will kill any non-numeric data that he might have had in there, rather than just the whitespace.

Comment: @PatrickCollins there is nothing in the original question about additional situations to handle, this is the recommended method unless it doesn't fulfill the OP's specific data

Comment: Thank you Patrick for the heads up, however in this particular isstance, I do not have any non numerical data so Ed's solution worked perfectly.  Thank you (you have both received an upvote!)

Comment: df.convert_objects() has been deprecated since v0.21.0. The preferred solution is now df.Age = pd.to_numeric(df['Age']).fillna(0)

Answer (score 4):

```
merged['Age'] = merged['Age'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == ' ' else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer modified from [this, more thorough question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas). I'll make it a little bit more Pythonic and resolve your `basestring` issue.

```
def ws_to_zero(maybe_ws):
    try:
        if maybe_ws.isspace():
            return 0
        else:
            return maybe_ws
    except AttributeError:
        return maybe_ws

d.applymap(ws_to_zero)
```

where `d` is your dataframe.

Comment: Hi Patrick, tried this actually when I was researching -- I get an error that basestring isn't recognized!

Comment: @user3682157 What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 3.4 is what i'm using

Comment: @user3682157 The issue is that `basestring` has been collapsed to `str` in py3k. You could fix it by switching out `str` for `basestring`. But the solution I posted is closer to the preferred way of handling things like this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use NumPy, then you can use the below snippet:

```
import numpy as np    
df['column_of_interest'] = np.where(df['column_of_interest']==' ',0,df['column_of_interest']).astype(float)
```

While Paulo's response is excellent, my snippet above may be useful when multiple criteria are required during advanced data manipulation.