# fill NaN with values from a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, pandas, nan, fill

Hi I have a list( tranforming a numpy array to list) that contains a number of values. I try to use it to replace all of the NaN values that I have in a pandas column but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"
```

The line of code I use to do the fill is

```
df.column.fillna(list,inplace=True)
```

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: error is clear, did you read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna)?

Comment: The documentation clearly states : IT CANNOT BE A LIST

Comment: any way in which I can use a list. My fillna, was a try I had at fixing the problem I have not the only solution

Comment: How would you use a list? Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is with pass a scalar or a dict which is what is accepted by that method. Why must you use a list?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, by transforming my list to a series and that creating a new column with that series. After which I replaced all NaN's with values from the new column as per [Python Pandas replace NaN in one column with value from corresponding row of second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177498/python-pandas-replace-nan-in-one-column-with-value-from-corresponding-row-of-sec)

This seems to me like a bit of a long way for what I thought might be easier in python.
Thanks for stating the obvious EdChum ;)