# Pandas: replace Nan with values from one of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Given the following dataframe `df`, where `df['B']=df['M1']+df['M2']`:

```
   A    M1   M2   B
   1    1    2    3
   1    2    NaN  NaN
   1    3    6    9
   1    4    8    12
   1    NaN  10   NaN
   1    6    12   18
```

I want the `NaN` in column `B` to equal the corresponding value in `M1` or `M2` provided that the latter is not `NaN`:

```
   A    M1   M2   B
   1    1    2    3
   1    2    NaN  2
   1    3    6    9
   1    4    8    12
   1    NaN  10   10
   1    6    12   18
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44973587/5110870) suggested to use:

`df.loc[df['B'].isnull(),'B'] = df['M1']`, but the structure of this line allows to consider either `M1` or `M2`, and not both at the same time.

Ideas on how I should change it to consider both columns?

**EDIT**

Not a duplicate question! For ease of understanding, I claimed that `df['B']=df['M1']+df['M2']`, but in my real case, `df['B']` is not a sum and comes from a rather complicated computation. So I cannot apply a simple formula to `df['B']`: all I can do is change the `NaN` values to match the corresponding value in either `M1` or `M2`.

Comment: You need `df['B']=df['M1'].add(df['M2'], fill_value=0)`, it seems it is dupe...

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11106823/2901002)

Comment: `df[['M2','M1']].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael would you mind if I mark as dupl ?

Comment: @Wen - no problem.

Comment: Not a dupe guys. Check the edit please.

Comment: @FaCoffee it's a dup of a different question then, you want to use `pandas.combine_first`

Comment: Not at all! `pandas.combine_first` allows some rows to disappear, while I don't want this.

Comment: @FaCoffee fillna by using `df.B.fillna(df[['M2','M1']].max(1))`

Comment: @FaCoffee - I think `Wen` think `df['B']= (df['M1']+ df['M2']).fillna(df[['M2','M1']].max(1))`, another solution is `df['B']= (df['M1']+ df['M2']).fillna(df[['M2','M1']].sum(1))`

Comment: @FaCoffee yeah , jez is right , you just need to assign it back `df.B=df.B.fillna(df[['M2','M1']].max(1))`

Comment: This works! Someone should make it an answer!

Comment: @Wen - please add answer ;)

Comment: @jezrael ok will do

Comment: @jezrael add it , feel free to modify :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base on our discussion above in the comment

```
df.B=df.B.fillna(df[['M1','M2']].max(1))
df
Out[52]: 
   A   M1    M2     B
0  1  1.0   2.0   3.0
1  1  2.0   NaN   2.0
2  1  3.0   6.0   9.0
3  1  4.0   8.0  12.0
4  1  NaN  10.0  10.0
5  1  6.0  12.0  18.0
```

From  jezrael

```
df['B']= (df['M1']+ df['M2']).fillna(df[['M2','M1']].sum(1))
```

Comment: @jezrael no worry , I think op also help himself :-)

Comment: @Wen - ya, it is up to you, but I think the best is change from wiki to normal answer ;) Good luck!