# Python Pandas replace NaN in one column with value from another column of the same row it has be as list column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
data = {

'id' :[70,70,1148,557,557,104,581,69],
'r_id' : [[70,34, 44, 23, 11, 71], [70, 53, 33, 73, 41], 
          np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,[69, 68, 7],]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print (df)
     id                      r_id
0    70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1    70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2  1148                       NaN
3   557                       NaN
4   557                       NaN
5   104                       NaN
6   581                       NaN
7    69               [69, 68, 7]
```

Output dataframe,

```
data = {

'id' :[70,70,1148,557,557,104,581,69],
'r_id' : [[70,34, 44, 23, 11, 71], [70, 53, 33, 73, 41], 
          [1148], [557], [557], [104],[581],[69, 68, 7]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print (df)
     id                      r_id
0    70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1    70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2  1148                    [1148]
3   557                     [557]
4   557                     [557]
5   104                     [104]
6   581                     [581]
7    69               [69, 68, 7]
```

I want the target column r_id with a list column the source column id is not a  list, referred the below links in stackoverflow,
[python-pandas-replace-nan-in-one-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177498/python-pandas-replace-nan-in-one-column-with-value-from-corresponding-row-of-sec)
Tried the following as well, data_merge_rel.RELATED_DEVICE.fillna(data_merge_rel.DF0_Desc_Label_i.to_list(), inplace=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `list_comprehension` + `Series.fillna`.

First we create a list with all the `id` values converted to `list` type.
Then we replace `NaN` here by our list values:

```
df['temp'] = [[x] for x in df['id']]
df['r_id'] = df['r_id'].fillna(df['temp'])
df = df.drop(columns='temp')
```

Or in one line using `apply` (thanks *r.ook*)

```
df['r_id'] = df['r_id'].fillna(df['id'].apply(lambda x: [x]))
```

```
     id                      r_id
0    70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1    70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2  1148                    [1148]
3   557                     [557]
4   557                     [557]
5   104                     [104]
6   581                     [581]
7    69               [69, 68, 7]
```

Comment: If you are using list comprehension, why not `df['r_id'].fillna(df['id'].apply(lambda x: [x]))`?

Comment: Yes was thinking about it as well. But went for the more "readable" approach. But added it as second option. Thanks @r.ook

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
(df.explode('r_id').ffill(axis=1).reset_index().groupby(['index','id'],sort=False).agg(list)
                                                               .reset_index(1))
```

---

```
         id                      r_id
index                                
0        70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1        70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2      1148                    [1148]
3       557                     [557]
4       557                     [557]
5       104                     [104]
6       581                     [581]
7        69               [69, 68, 7]
```

Comment: Thanking you, can you post both the solution, I have a bigger dataframe need to see the performance as well

Comment: I thought you had two solution one with explode and an another with group by

Comment: It went and did the same operation on other columns as well :(

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham you can use the column name before agg such as `.groupby(['index','id'],sort=False)['r_id'].agg(list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the column id to an array, add a dimension, then make a list of it and `fillna` with a Series like:

```
df['r_id'] = df['r_id'].fillna(pd.Series(df.id.to_numpy()[:,None].tolist(), index=df.index))
print (df)
     id                      r_id
0    70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1    70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2  1148                    [1148]
3   557                     [557]
4   557                     [557]
5   104                     [104]
6   581                     [581]
7    69               [69, 68, 7]
```

or if you don't have a lot of `nan`, it may worth to select only these rows prior to do anything:

```
mask_na = df.r_id.isna()
df.loc[mask_na, 'r_id'] = pd.Series(df.loc[mask_na,'id'].to_numpy()[:,None].tolist(), 
                                    index=df[mask_na].index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think anky_91's answer will be faster, but you could also try this:

```
df['r_id'] = np.where(df['r_id'].isnull(),
                      df['id'].apply(lambda x: [x]),
                      df['r_id'])
```

Output:

```
     id                      r_id
0    70  [70, 34, 44, 23, 11, 71]
1    70      [70, 53, 33, 73, 41]
2  1148                    [1148]
3   557                     [557]
4   557                     [557]
5   104                     [104]
6   581                     [581]
7    69               [69, 68, 7]
```