# replacing empty strings with NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a pandas dataframe (that was created by importing a csv file). I want to replace blank values with NaN. Some of these blank values are empty and some contain a (variable number) of spaces `''`, `' '`, `'    '`, etc.

Using the suggestion from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas) I have

```
df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True, inplace = True)
```

which does replace all the strings that only contain spaces, but also replaces every string that has a space in it, which is not what I want.

How do I replace only strings with *just* spaces and empty strings?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas

Comment: @NickK9 I linked to that thread in my question. The question and accepted answer replace cells containing _any_ white space. My question is about replacing cells containing _only_ white space. So, I disagree that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are reading a `csv` file and want to convert all empty strings to `nan` **while reading the file** itself then you can use the option

```
skipinitialspace=True
```

Example code

```
pd.read_csv('Sample.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

This will remove any white spaces that appear after the delimiters, Thus making all the empty strings as `nan`

From the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

> [image]

***Note:*** This option will remove preceding white spaces even from valid data, if for any reason you want to retain the preceding white space then this option is not a good choice.

Answer (score 20):

Indicate it has to start with blank and end with blanks with ^ and $ :

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: This would also trap strings embedded in spaces such as ' thisstring ' but it will work for my dataset.

Comment: @Boud shouldn't the pattern to replace really be  r'^\s*$' instead. the original answer doesn't match empty string ''.

Comment: @Boud stumbled upon this answer when i was stuck at not able replace few empty cells with replace().. this worked perfectly. thanks