# replace blank string with nan

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to replace an empty string " " in a pandas dataframe column. The dtype of that column is "O". 
Ive tried using

```
df[col].replace(" ", np.nan, inplace = True)
```

However, I get a nonetype object in return or the whole column is erased. I've also tried using

```
df[col].dropna(axis=0, subset=['CLOSED_TIME'])
```

I should also mention the column is a bunch of dates/time but not in datetime format. My goal is to fill the empty strings with nan, so that i can run .fillna(0) on the whole dataframe.

Comment: The first line should work.  I would suggest pasting the entire traceback

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing `df[col] = ... inplace=True)` You shouldn't assign **and** specify an inplace operation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replacing empty strings with NaN in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711900/replacing-empty-strings-with-nan-in-pandas)

Comment: @Chris it won't work if the spaces are of variable len.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `df[col].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!