# python pandas merge two or more lines of text into one line

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have data frame with text data like below,

```
    name | address                  | number 
1   Bob    bob                        No.56
2          @gmail.com           
3   Carly  carly@world.com            No.90
4   Gorge  greg@yahoo     
5          .com                   
6                                     No.100
```

and want to make it like this frame.

```
    name | address               | number 
1   Bob    bob@gmail.com           No.56
2   Carly  carly@world.com         No.90                 
3   Gorge  greg@yahoo.com          No.100
```

I am using pandas to read file but not sure how to use merge or concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `name` column consists of unique values,

```
print df

    name          address  number
0    Bob              bob   No.56
1    NaN       @gmail.com     NaN
2  Carly  carly@world.com   No.90
3  Gorge       greg@yahoo     NaN
4    NaN             .com     NaN
5    NaN              NaN  No.100

df['name'] = df['name'].ffill()
print df.fillna('').groupby(['name'], as_index=False).sum()

    name          address  number
0    Bob    bob@gmail.com   No.56
1  Carly  carly@world.com   No.90
2  Gorge   greg@yahoo.com  No.100
```

you may need `ffill()`, `bfill()`, `[::-1]`, `.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x['address']))`, `strip()`, `lstrip()`, `rstrip()`, `replace()` kind of thing to extend above code to more complicated data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a data frame of sex rows (with possible `NaN` entry in each column), there might be no direct `pandas` methods for that.

You will need some codes to assign the value in `name` column, so that pandas can know the split rows of `bob` and `@gmail.com` belong to same user `Bob`.

You can fill each empty entry in column `name` with its preceding user using the `fillna` or `ffill` methods, see [pandas dataframe missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#cleaning-filling-missing-data).

```
df ['name'] = df['name'].ffill()

# gives
    name    address number
0   Bob bob No.56
1   Bob @gmail.com  
2   Carly   carly@world.com No.90
3   Gorge   greg@yahoo  
4   Gorge   .com    
5   Gorge       No.100
```

Then you can use the `groupby` and `sum` as the aggregation function.

```
df.groupby(['name']).sum().reset_index()

# gives
    name    address number
0   Bob bob@gmail.com   No.56
1   Carly   carly@world.com No.90
2   Gorge   greg@yahoo.com  No.100
```

You may find converting between `NaN` and white space useful, see [Replacing blank values (white space) with NaN in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas) and [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).