# Assigning value to a new column based on the values of other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following is a sub-set of  data frame:

```
id  words  A   B   C   D  E  
1   new    1       1   
2   good   1  
3   star            1
4   never                  
5   final
```

I want to define a new variable (called FF) as a new column and assign 1 to it, if values for all other variables (columns) are "null". The new data frame would be like this:

```
id  words  A   B   C   D  E  FF
1   new    1       1   
2   good   1  
3   star            1
4   never                     1                
5   final                     1
```

How I can do it using python and Pandas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a function that is applied row-wise to the data frame:

```
def fill_if_nan(row):
    if row[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].isnull().all():
        return 1

    return None

df['FF'] = df.apply(fill_if_nan, axis=1)
```

Or a more elegant numpy based solution:

```
df['FF'] = np.where(df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].isnull().all(1), 1, np.nan)
```

Comment: thank you. The program can not recognize the null valuse. For some rows, all the values for the variables are null, but the FF variable does not have "1". I  think I need to replase all spaces to null values. Do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: In case you want to replace a space by `nan` you can use `df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas).

Comment: I tried it, but it also replace the colmns of words with null values if there are several words in the column and there is space between them , how I can say except the column "word".

Comment: @Mary You need to explicitly specify the columns as in `df[['A', 'B', ...]].replace(...)` and assign it back to the df.