# Python: how to replace empty string with NaN in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that I read from a `.csv` file that contains some missing values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

df:
    Name       Age   Civil
0   Leonard    30    Engaged
1   Sheldon    31   
2   Howard           Married
3   Raj        29    Single
```

If I check the missing values in my Notebook it returns empty string, where

```
df['Civil'][1]:
'            '

type(df['Civil'][1]):
str
```

How can I replace empty string with `NaN`?

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810911/9209546) in the marked dup.