# Replace value in existing column .csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's say I have a csv where a sample row looks like: `[' ', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` where  indicates an empty cell. I want to iterate through all of the rows in the .csv and replace all of the values in the first column for each row with another value, i.e. `[100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. How could this be done? It's also worth noting that the columns don't have labels (they were converted from an .xlsx).

Currently, I'm trying this:

```
for i, row in test.iterrows():
    value = randomFunc(x, row)

    test.loc[test.index[i], 0] = value
```

But this adds a column at the end with the label 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing blank values (white space) with NaN in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas)

Comment: @ ch1marea,  if any of the answers best fits into your question you can mark  that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first column by position with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by regex for zero or more whitespaces:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        0:['',20,' '],
         1:[20,10,20]
})


df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].replace('^\s*$',100, regex=True)
print (df)
     0   1
0  100  20
1   20  10
2  100  20
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a for loop while using pandas and numpy,

Just an example Below where we have `b`  and `c` are empty which is been replaced by `replace` method:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

>>> df
   0
a  1
b
c

>>> df.replace('', 100, inplace=True)
>>> df
     0
a    1
b  100
c  100
```

**Example to replace the empty cells in a Specific column:**

In the Below example we have two columns `col1` and `col2`, Where `col1` having an empty cells at index 2 and 4 in `col1`.

```
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    1    6
1    2    7
2
3    4
4        10
```

**Just to replace the above mentioned empty cells in `col1` only:**

However, when we say `col1` then it implies to all the rows down to the column itself which is handy in a sense.

```
>>> df.col1.replace('', 100, inplace=True)
>>> df
   col1 col2
0     1    6
1     2    7
2   100
3     4
4   100   10
```

**Another way around Just choosing the DataFrame column Specific:**

```
>>> df['col1'] =  df.col1.replace('', 100, regex=True)
>>> df
   col1 col2
0     1    6
1     2    7
2   100
3     4
4   100   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, ' ', 2, 3, ' ', 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7])
df[df[0] == " "] = rd.randint(0,100)
```

The output is:

```
    0
0   1
1   10
2   2
3   3
4   67
5   5
6   5
7   5
8   6
9   7
10  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `csv` module

```
import csv
your_value = 100    # value that you want to replace with
with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        row[0] = your_value
        writer.writerow(row)
```