# Get 'TypeError: data type not understood' When Replacing Zeros With Previous Non-zero Values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I get '**TypeError:** data type not understood' when trying to execute a line of code that looks like this:

```
df['c'].replace(0, method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

The code above is basically to replace every zero value with its previous non-zero value in column `c`. The data type of values in column `c` is integer with only two NaNs. The error still occurs after replacing the NaNs with zeros, but it works fine when I add the following line before the above code:

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

So what does actually happen here? How can I replace every zero value with its previous non-zero value in column `c` without deleting any row with NaNs in my DataFrame?

Comment: Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output?

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the column 'c'?

Comment: @SH-SF Basically it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13445241/3397819).

Comment: @Vishnudev It's Integer

Comment: Try `df['c'].replace(0, pd.np.nan).ffill()`?

Comment: @Vishnudev's answer replaces not only your zeros with the previous value, but also the other NaNs. Is this desired?

Comment: I think handling `NaN` should be done beforehand rather than persisting it. What I am expecting is a non-NaN column.

Comment: @Vishnudev Ahh, it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Trenton_M Yes, it does work. But it does not answer the 'why' yet. And I prefer to wait for a moment before accepting an answer.

Comment: There's no way to really answer why, unless you post all your real data.

Comment: @Trenton_M You are totally correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the missing data are handled i.e. `NaNs` replaced with some desired value,

```
some_desired_value = 0 # Maybe different in your case
df['c'] = df['c'].fillna(some_desired_value)
```

Replace zeros with `NaN` and then forward-fill

```
df['c'].replace(0, pd.np.nan).ffill()
```

Even your code should work if there are no undesired value in column

```
df['c'].replace(0, method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This works fine. But why did the error occur using my code?

Comment: As I said there might be some undesired value in the column. Maybe it's not visually seen. It may be some non-ASCII character. You'll need to evaluate the data more carefully for this.

Comment: Also, try using `pd.to_numeric` and see if raises an error.

Comment: I use dtype 'Int32' so that it can handle the NaNs

Comment: What do you mean? Did you use `astype`?

Comment: Basically I use this `df['c'] = df.groupby(...).diff().fillna(...).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype('Int32')` when trying to create `df['c']`. Afterward, I use the above code.

Comment: You cant aggregate and assign to same dataframe as the size will be different

Comment: I think you have different issue. That's a totally different question. For now, I am ending it here