# how to replace empty string with null in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, dbnull

[empty string like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqkMr.png)    [isnull() not find empty string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jylmn.png)

```
conn = connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',password='root',database='spiderdata',charset='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from beikedata_community1',con=conn)
df
df.subway.isnull()

**i want to use 'isnull()' find missing value, but it's not support empty string, what can i do? thanks very much!**
```

Comment: i want to use 'isnull()' find missing value, but it's not support empty string, what can i do? thanks very much

Comment: `df.replace(r'', np.NaN)`? Does [Replacing blank values (white space) with NaN in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas) help you?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh wow! amazing! thanks very much!

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh excuse me!  your suggestion help me replace empty string, but i  found i can't use missingno find missing values, do you have good idea about this?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used that library before, maybe you could replace `np.NaN` in `df.replace(r'', np.NaN)` to some values that `missingno` can find.

Comment: okay! still thanks for your help! you are very nice!

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas @Golden Lion both not answer i want, still thanks for your help

Answer (score -2):

You can use print(df.replace(r' ', 'NaN')) .
This Replaces the empty cells with NaN.

Comment: but 'NaN' is also a string, i just want replace it make missingno  finding it, like None in python or null in mysql.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how your initial and final results would look like?

Comment: @ Anirudh i just want to find missing values with library like missingno  in my dataframe Conveniently，but empty string in raw data i have no means to deal with it.

Comment: Can you share a before and after version of the dataframe ? I am still unable to comprehend

Comment: Post the desired output.  I gave you an answer that all data science preprocessing use dd.fillna(0).  You can also use bfill to backfill missing values

Comment: [link](https://github.com/hengyanchen/beike_data/blob/main/%E8%B4%9D%E5%A3%B3%E7%BD%91%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E6%8E%A2%E7%B4%A2%E6%80%A7%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90.ipynb)**this is my data jupyter note,null values in subway can't find by missingno or df.isnull(), i also can't use dd.fillna(0)  to replace it**

Comment: by the way ,sometimes we need to replace missing values with median,isn't it?

Comment: I think I got what you are trying to say. You can replace an empty/missing cell with a string like 'NaN'. Then if you use df.dropna on your dataframe or if you count the NaN/missing values, you get the answer. There are a lot of techniques to play around with missing data and one among them is replacing with median

Comment: @ Golden Lion @Anirudh you are right, i think i made a stupid mistake, i don't use inplace=True cause i think your way didin't work.hahaha! my fault! thank you again