# remove rows that are empty from column type object pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to remove some blank rows from my dataframe. Since it is an object column, i convert it to string column

`reviewsCleanDF['clean_review'] = reviewsCleanDF['clean_review'].astype(str)`

which doesn't convert at all.

My idea was to convert it to string column and use

```
reviewsCleanDF.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True)
reviewsCleanDF.dropna(subset = ["clean_review"], inplace=True)
reviewsCleanDF.reset_index(drop=True)
```

As you can see, at index 607323, it is blank.

[image: blank row]

Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Can you try `reviewsCleanDF.replace(r'^\s*$, np.nan, inplace=True)` ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942746/2901002) for solution.

Comment: @jezrael hi i tried your method and i got "EOL while scanning string literal" error

Comment: sorry, need `r'^\s*$'`

Comment: I check your link and put "df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)"
It finally solve. Thank you!