# Getting rows where multiple columns are not blank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like so

```
id  col_1 col_2 col_3
101 1     17    12
102       17    
103             4
    2
```

how do i only records where col_1, col_2, and col_3 are not blank?

**Expected output:**

```
id  col_1 col_2 col_3
101 1     17    12
```

Comment: For *blank* data, you should include the output of `df.to_dict()` rather than the print out.

Comment: In case some of your "blank" data actualy consists of spaces, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942746/14627505). From it, you can use `df.replace(r'^\s*$', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This will select only those rows in the dataframe, where all `['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']` are non-empty:

```py
df[df[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']].ne('').all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I'm not checking it it's na but rather blank. and i dont want to include all columns

Comment: @Eisen does it work for you now?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it
make a list of the blank, nulls etc and then convert the columns that has any of these values into a True/False, and take their sum. you need the rows where sum is zero

```
df[df.isin ([' ','', np.nan]).astype(int).sum(axis=1).eq(0)]
```

```
id  col_1   col_2   col_3
0   101     1   17  12
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `DataFrame.query()`:

```py
df = df.query(' and '.join([f'{col}!=""' for col in ['col_1','col_2','col_3']]))
```

Alternatively you can do it this way:

```py
df = df[lambda x: (x.drop(columns='id') != "").all(axis=1)]
```